# SQL server query help

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with following relationship.

```
TABLE_A:
 A_ID
 Name

TABLE_B:
 B_Id
 B_DESC
 A_ID

TABLE_C:
  C_ID
  C_DESC
  B_ID
```

I am trying to write the following query to get the results. For each A_ID there are many rows in TABLE_B and TABLE_C has many rows for each B_ID. Could you please let me know how to write the query to the results? Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT B_ID, B_DESC, C_DESC FROM TABLE_B B JOIN TABLE_C C on B.B_Id = C.C_ID WHERE A_ID = 4
```

The Format I am trying to get:

```
    B_ID   B_DESC
        C_DESC1
        C_DESC2
        .......
    B_ID    B_DESC
        C_DESC1
        C_DESC2
        C_DESC3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think my query is right. I am trying to get many to many results for A_ID.

Answer (score 1):

You're joining B_ID to C_ID; try the following:

```
SELECT 
 B_ID, 
 B_DESC, 
 C_DESC 
FROM 
 TABLE_B B 
 JOIN TABLE_C C 
  on B.B_ID = C.B_ID 
WHERE A_ID = 4
```

Comment: This query only one row from TABLE_C. I have many rows in TABLE_C for each TABLE_B row. I am trying to get master detail records between TABLE_B and TABLE_C.

Comment: This will retrieve C_DESC for all rows in TABLE_C that have B_ID matching any TABLE_B rows with A_ID = 4. If you're only getting one row, you have one row in TABLE_B with A_ID = 4 and one row in TABLE_C with B_ID matching that in the TABLE_B row.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started...

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A 
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON 
        (B.A_ID = A.A_ID)
    INNER JOIN TABLE_C C ON
       (C.B_ID = B.B_ID)
WHERE A.A_ID = 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from TABLE_A ta
join TABLE_B tb on tb.A_ID = ta.A_ID
join TABLE_C tc on tc.B_ID = tb.B_ID
where ta.A_ID = 4
```